# TS2304: Cannot find name

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

HI there guy's i'm relatively new on Typescript and Angular and i try figure out in this case: i got the erro below error on ng build, but in ng serve everything going well.. Whats strange issue is this. Also i want to make some declaration privete but with private doesen't work. Need to understand more some tricks probably...

TS2304: Cannot find name 'ngRedux'.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { PayPalConfig, PayPalEnvironment, PayPalIntegrationType } from 'ngx-paypal';
import { MatRadioChange } from '@angular/material';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { UsersProvider} from '../../../../../providers/users.provider';
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import {IAppState} from '../../../../../reducers';


declare let paypal: any;
@Component({
  selector     : 'abbonamento',
  templateUrl  : './abbonamento.component.html',
  styleUrls    : ['./abbonamento.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AbbonamentoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewChecked
{
  addScript: boolean = false;
  paypalLoad: boolean = true;
  public finalAmount: number = 1;
  abbonamenti = [];
  caratteristiche = [];
  public PayPalConfig?: PayPalConfig;
  constructor(
    public http: Http,
    public cookieService: CookieService,
    public ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>,
  )
  {

  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.http.get('https://dev.site.it/get-abbonamenti').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      this.abbonamenti = data.abbonamenti;
      this.caratteristiche = data.caratteristiche;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy()
  {
  }


  payPalConfig = {
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
      sandbox: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      production: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    commit: true,

    // payment() is called when the button is clicked
    payment: function (data, actions) {
      // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
      let prezzo = cookieService.get('importo');
      return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {
          transactions: [
            {
              amount: {total: prezzo, currency: 'EUR'}
            }
          ]

        }
      })
    },
    // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

      // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
      return actions.payment.execute().then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        var data = {
          user_id: ngRedux.getState().session,
          dati_transazione: response,
        }
        http.post('https://dev.sito.it/aggiorna-abbonamento', data).subscribe(data=> {});
        window.alert('Pagamento confermato');
      });
    }
}

  pianoChange(event: MatRadioChange)
  {
    this.cookieService.set( 'importo', event.value );
  }


  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (!this.addScript) {
      this.addPaypalScript().then(() => {
          paypal.Button.render(this.payPalConfig, '#paypal-checkout-btn');
          this.paypalLoad = false;
        })
      }
  }

  addPaypalScript() {
    this.addScript = true;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let scripttagElement = document.createElement('script');
      scripttagElement.src = 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js';
      scripttagElement.onload = resolve;
      document.body.appendChild(scripttagElement);
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Search for this line of the `onAuthorize()` function:

```
user_id: ngRedux.getState().session,
```

Change it to this:

```
user_id: this.ngRedux.getState().session,
```

You are accessing a class variable not a function local variable, so you need to specify the `this` keyword.

All this assumes that you have the `@angular-redux` library property installed as part of your project and that the `NgRedux<IAppState>` is set up as a provider in your `@NgModule`.

Comment: I got this error now: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

Comment: That makes me think that your `ngRedux` class is not set up as an injectable provider.  I don't know anything about the `angular-redux` library, but be sure you are setting it up as a provider in the current application.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you might have some variables declared as `private` but which are still being used in the template of a particular component.

The way around this is to make all those properties that you will be using in the template as `public` and the rest and `private`. Doing this should fix the issue for you.

The overall idea here is, if you want to use anything from a file outside that file, you'll have to declare it as `public` otherwise you're going to get errors while building.

Comment: how i can to this?